# To have a nicely balanced physique what strength comparisons should you have?

Tags: weightlifting, bodybuilding, strength-training

So compare your squat to bench press, bench press to overhead press and overhead press to bicep curl for example.

Comment: I’m not sure that there is a answer to this other than knowing that everyone is different. If you want a general sense of how you compare to others, follow this link ---> https://strengthlevel.com

Comment: Are you looking for a mathematical equation?

Answer (score 1):

EXRX has a set of [strength standards](https://exrx.net/Testing/WeightLifting/StrengthStandards) that cover the basic compound lifts. If you can get to "advanced" on all of the columns I think you'll look pretty good and objectively you'll be quite strong.